# Merging MultiPolygon and MultiLinestring

Tags: qgis, merge, multipart, multi-polygon

I want to merge a Multipolygon with a MultiLinestring however I cannot merge the data as they are of different types.

One solution was to create a minimal buffer around the MultiLinestring and merge with the MultiPolgyon, however while the attributes merge together I cannot see the lines (in this case waterlines, and the MultiPolygon are of Parks) during the visualisation.

Are there any other alternatives?
This is what my map looks like when merging four layers:

(I have made a mistake - its not roads for MultiLinestring but waterlines as paths)

[image]

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a screenshot of your current map, as well as an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It doesn't really make any sense to append roads to parks or parks to roads. Maybe you want to Intersect the two so that roads are attributed with park, and are split where the park changes?

Comment: Why do you want to merge them, what is your next step?

Comment: @BERA That is a good point as I am rather new to geospatial processing so this is a great time to get some support on my methodology. Essentially, I wish to understand the popularity of parks across the UK. The purpose of including the layers `surface water` & `waterline` was for potential 'park-sports', such as canoeing, or even fishing. Woodlands were included for trailing paths. If I could merge these together, I was aiming to do some processing with them on R while as a single file

Comment: Okay, so the Question, as written, is an XY Problem. Rather than changing the question with a comment, I suggest you rewrite the Question to describe your problem, with the understanding that soliciting opinions on how to do the research is off-topic here. It's not clear why the amenities need to be merged to be quantified or summarized by park -- wouldn't a simple table with kilometers or hectares of each amenity be enough?